# How to make my iOS APP share files directily to another APP like Workflow "Open in" action

Tags: ios

Here is the Workflow Action. It seems that Workflow can send a file to another APP directily. Any ideas?

The normal way to send a file to another APP is using Share Extension, but Workflow APP could send it directily without showing the Action Sheet and selecting an APP.

[image: like this]

If you set an action like this and run your workflow, it just open the selected APP and that APP got the file.

So I just want to know is there any way to make it happen? Or it just a secret API of iOS and Workflow just use it because of the purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Your exact question needs to be stated more clearly (e.g. exactly WHAT you are trying to accomplish instead of just "integrate").  To get you started, some quick info:

At my last check, Workflow integrates with apps in a few main ways:

1) Via the iOS sharing/share-sheet interface.

2) Built-in support for the app within Workflow itself.

3) *(of course, Workflow can also leverage Callback URI's of other apps to integrate with them like any other app can.)*

If you want to have direct, built-in support from Workflow, the Workflow team itself must add the support into the Workflow app.  This is easier for them (and others) if your app exposes a proper API with functions that allow direct integration.

Going into this further is too broad of a topic for a quick answer.  I hope this helps some.